# Failing while building aosp android

Tags: android, android-source, meson-build

Build fails with this error, how to fix it?

```
FAILED: out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/.build.timestamp
/bin/bash -c "(rm -rf out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/ ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/ ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D//build ) && (cp -r external/mesa3d//* out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/ ) && (cd out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D && PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:\$PATH meson ./build --cross-file /home/gogamid/sa-arpi-12L/out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D_GEN/aosp_cross --buildtype=release -Ddri-search-path=/vendor/lib64/dri -Dplatforms=android -Dplatform-sdk-version=32 -Ddri-drivers= -Dgallium-drivers=v3d,vc4 -Dvulkan-drivers=broadcom -Dgbm=enabled -Degl=enabled -Dcpp_rtti=false ) && (PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:\$PATH ninja -C out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/build ) && (touch out/target/product/rpi/obj/MESON_MESA3D/.build.timestamp )"
/bin/bash: meson: command not found
19:10:40 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make sure you have python3.8 as default for python or python3 command, you can do that by running these commands:

```
#configure python
sudo apt install libssl-dev python3-setuptools
#install python3.8 and set as default
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
#choose 2 (python3.8) as default
#link python to python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
Then you can update meson

#update meson
sudo apt-get remove meson
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools \
                       python3-wheel ninja-build
pip3 install --user meson
#move meson from local to root
sudo mv .local/bin/meson /usr/bin/
source .profile
```

Comment: Nice, you save my time. The key is the meson must be installed by python3.8, not by  apt or other python.